# How do I retrieve URLs that are used when clicking buttons on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, url, post

On this website I need to download 17 xlsx files after picking the names in a dropdown window. This must be automated so I need the 17 URLs to be transferred using HTTP.

This is the HTML code related to this part:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <strong> Listino </strong><br>
    <form action="https://b2b.bergamaschi.com/commerciale/listino-personalizzato" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cliente" class="form-control" value="008701"> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <!-- <label class="control-label mb-1"> Linea: </label> -->
      <select class="form-control" id="linea" name="linea" required="">
       <option value="*" selected=""> TUTTE LE LINEE </option>
       <option value="AC">ACCESSORISTICA</option>
       <option value="AM">AMMORTIZZATORI</option>
       <option value="AO">ATTREZZATURE PROFESSIONALI</option>
       <option value="BA">BATTERIE</option>
       <option value="CA">CANDELE</option>
       <option value="CS">CASCHI</option>
       <option value="FA">FANALERIA E LAMPADE</option>
       <option value="FI">FILTRI</option>
       <option value="GD">KIT E VARIE</option>
       <option value="LG">LOGISTICA</option>
       <option value="LU">LUBRIFICANTI</option>
       <option value="OE">MOBILITA' ELETTRICA</option>
       <option value="PN">PNEUMATICI</option>
       <option value="RE">RICAMBI ELETTRICI</option>
       <option value="RI">RICAMBISTICA</option>
       <option value="FR">SISTEMI FRENANTI</option>
       <option value="TM">TRASMISSIONI MOTO</option>
       <option value="TR">TRASMISSIONI SCOOTER</option>
      </select>
     </div>  
     <div class="form-group">
      <button name="xls" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
       <span>Scarica XLS </span>
      </button>
      <button name="pdf" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
       <span>Scarica PDF </span>
      </button>
     </div>    
    </form>
   </div>
```

Manually I'd need to pick the name in a dropdown window (select tag) and click a button (the first one, named "xls").

I tried with no success:

- right-click, inspect
- event listener tab
- network tab
- to use the link given in the form tag
- python selenium, href attribute in none

I think that here since the request is a POST one I cannot retrieve those URLs on the browser in the developer tools.

How can I get those URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of a select option:

`<select class="form-control mr-3" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">`
then write the function for it:

```
<script>
function changeFunc() {
    $('#myImageId').show();
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
}</script>
```